# Why this is not working well?

Tags: python-3.x

Why print last line? That line must print when not found 'word' at all???

```
with open(name) as f:
    all_Line-s = f.read_lines()
    for line_Number in range( l en (all_Lines)):
        if word in all_Lines[line_Number]:
            print(word,"found in line {0}".format(line_Number+1))
            continue
    else:
       print(word,'not found')
```

Result:

```
'word' found in line 3
'word' found in line 6
'word' found in line 43
'word' not found
```

i switch 'if' and 'else' and use break but ...

Comment: `else` after a loop means "unless there was a break"

Comment: You should read on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` in a `for/else` executes if the `for` loop completes without encountering a `break`.

You could use a flag to control whether the "not found" message is printed:

```
with open....:
    found = False
    ...
    for line...:
        if word in ...:
            found = True
        ...
    ...
    if not found:
        print(word, 'not found')
```